# mysql innodb table recovery

Tags: mysql

Background info :We are upgrading the database to percona build version and the server was hung for two hours. We then cancelled it and we tried to recover the table but it's not recovering

```
  - I tried mysqlcheck -r to repair but did not work
  - I am not able to create table - it says table already exists
  - I am not able to drop table - it says table not found ...how do I resolve this
```

Comment: mysqlcheck is useless for INNODB. you can add your mysql error log ?

Comment: Here's the dba.stackexchange.com link to recover InnoDB table spaces: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6268/how-to-recover-an-innodb-table-whose-files-were-moved-around/6269#6269